# System.import inside imported module breaks other System.import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I've run into a strange issue related to Webpack's code splitting, strictly speaking - with importing modules by System.import. Problem is that a certain System.import always breaks at first attempt, but at second attempt and later it works normally.

There are four actors in the show: `app.js`, `mock.js`, `request_1.js` and `contact_support.js`.

**1.**
 **`app.js`** - on load: imports `mock.js`, dynamically imports `contact-support.js` on button click

```
import mock from 'mock'; // removing this solves problem with contact-support.js, but why?
(...)
$('document').ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '[data-target="#contactSupport"]', function () {
                System.import('contact-support')
                    .then(module => {
                        console.log('contact-support loaded');
                    });
            });
});
```

**2.** 
**`mock.js`** - loads correctly, dynamically imports `request_1.js`

```
(...)
System.import('request_1').then(response => {
    return fnOK(response.default());
});
```

**3. `request_1.js`** - loads correctly

**4. `contact-support.js`** - **not loaded at first System.import** in `app.js`, then loads normally

---

At initial load everything seems to load fine, but when I click on button that triggers System.import in `app.js` that should load `contact-support.js` this is what happens:

1. first click in `app.js` (should dynamically load `contact-support.js`) - **breaks**:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>
> > `modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, **webpack_require**)

2. second click in `app.js` - **works**:

> contact-support loaded

---

If I remove `import mock from 'mock'` from `app.js`, then `contact-support.js` always loads correctly, so it appears Webpack has problem with identyfing which chunk should be loaded.

With my current configuration file chunks coming from `mock.js` (which is imported by `app.js`) are also assigned to original `app.js`, so they might run into conflict with other chunks assigned to `app.js`, such as `contact-support`. To prevent this, I've switched from using numbers to chunk hashes in chunk filenames, but this didn't solve the problem.

---

**EDIT: I've managed to reproduce the issue on as [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487906/system-import-fails-at-first-attempt-modulesmoduleid-is-undefined) as possible.**

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` - what's the stacktrace?

Comment: @OvidiuDolha it comes from Webpack's require function: `modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);`