# System.import fails at first attempt (modules[moduleId] is undefined)

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, webpack-2

When I use `System.import()` more than once in separate modules one of them doesn't work on first try (Webpack's require function returns `modules[moduleId] is undefined`), but at second and at subsequent attempts it loads normally.

Folder structure

```
[webpack-test]
----[modules]
--------foo.js
--------bar.js
--------dateHelper.js
----[node_modules]
----0.app.dist.js
----0.charts.dist.js
----1.app.dist.js
----3.app.dist.js
----app.dist.js
----app.js
----charts.dist.js
----charts.js
----index.html
----package.json
----webpack.config.js
```

---

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="./app.dist.js"></script>
<script src="./charts.dist.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.3"
  }
}
```

---

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function () {
    return [
        // APP:
        {
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    path.resolve('./modules/')
                ]
            },
            entry:   './app.js',
            output:  {
                filename: 'app.dist.js',
            }
        },

        // CHARTS:
        {
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    path.resolve('./modules/')
                ]
            },
            entry:   './charts.js',
            output:  {
                filename: 'charts.dist.js',
            }
        }
    ];
};
```

---

app.js

```
export default (function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        System.import('foo').then(foo => { // breaks at first attempt
            console.log('foo imported');
        });
        System.import('bar').then(bar => {
            console.log('bar imported');
        });
    }, 3000);
})();
```

---

foo.js

```
export default (function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
})();
```

---

bar.js

```
export default (function bar() {
    console.log('bar');
})();
```

---

dateHelper.js

```
export default (function dateHelper() {
    console.log('dateHelper');
})();
```

---

charts.js

```
export default (function charts() {
    System.import('dateHelper').then(dateHelper => {
        console.log('dateHelper imported');
    })
})();
```

---

Console output:

> 0.charts.dist.js:8 dateHelper
>
> charts.dist.js:152 dateHelper imported
>
> **app.dist.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ (app.dist.js:48)**
>
> > **modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);**
>
> 1.app.dist.js:8 bar
>
> app.dist.js:156 bar imported
>
> app.dist.js:153 foo imported
>
> app.dist.js:156 bar imported

**The output should be:**

> 0.charts.dist.js:8 dateHelper
>
> charts.dist.js:152 dateHelper imported
>
> 0.app.dist.js:8 foo
>
> app.dist.js:153 foo imported
>
> 1.app.dist.js:8 bar
>
> app.dist.js:156 bar imported
>
> app.dist.js:153 foo imported
>
> app.dist.js:156 bar imported